# Intent same activity

Tags: android

I have an issue. My program is suppose to go to different IP address with different names inside. It will then take out HTML code from the website. If it does not correspond to the correct name, it will skip to the next URL.

Here is the code for getting the username from the user, and accessing the webpage using webview.

```
    name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
    URL = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("URL"); //URL passed from previous activity as 99



            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                            "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");



                }

               /* public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    URL = URL +1 ;
                    Intent intent = new Intent (lightingpair.this, lightingpair.class);
                    intent.putExtra ("username", name) ;
                    intent.putExtra ("URL", URL);
                    startActivity (intent) ;

                }*/
            });

            webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.0." + URL + "/pair");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(URL) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is the code for the javascript

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    String nhtml;
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html) {

        nhtml = html ;

      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (nhtml.indexOf(name) > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(lightingpair.this, Lighting.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", name);
                    intent.putExtra("url", URL);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {

                    URL = URL + 1;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),lightingpair.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", name);
                    intent.putExtra("URL", URL);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

However, it stops after scanning after 3 or 4 webpages, sometimes it scans more. 
Was wondering whether there is a more efficient way to go to different IP address to collect HTML code.

Comment: The code where you are scanning HTML is not present, not sure we can help without that scanning logic.

Comment: Did you try scanning the web pages in a separate thread or a service?